# Angular - Custom method decorator which triggers console.log() at the beginning and end of a method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-decorator

I would like to know if it is possible to create a custom decorator in Angular which when applied to a method can achieve the following functionality:

1. console log at the beginning of a method
2. console log at the end of a method

Example:

**Without Decorator:**

```
getRelationshipSource() {
  console.log('Entering getRelationshipSource method');
  this.referenceDataService.getRefData('RLNSHPSC').subscribe(res => {
    this.relationshipSource$.next(res);
  });
  console.log('Leaving getRelationshipSource method');
}
```

**With Decorator**

```
@LogMethod()
getRelationshipSource() {
  this.referenceDataService.getRefData('RLNSHPSC').subscribe(res => {
    this.relationshipSource$.next(res);
  });
}
```

Comment: https://netbasal.com/inspiration-for-custom-decorators-in-angular-95aeb87f072c

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A method decorator does exactly what you want to do. It intercepts the call of the decorated method. So you are able to log before and after the call of the decorated method.

log.decorator.ts

```
export function log( ) : MethodDecorator {
  return function(target: Function, key: string, descriptor: any) {

    const originalMethod = descriptor.value; 

    descriptor.value =  function (...args: any[]) {

      console.log(`Entering ${key} method`);
      const result = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
      console.log(`Leaving ${key} method` );

      return result;
    }

    return descriptor;
  }
}
```

In this [SAMPLE APP](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-question-46953668?embed=1&file=app/log.decorator.ts) I used it in the `HelloComponent`.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { log } from './log.decorator';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;

  @log()
  ngOnInit() {
    this.Add(10, 32);
  }

  @log()
  private Add(a: number, b: number) : number {
    return a +  b;
  }
}
```

The console output looks like:

```
Entering ngOnInit method
Entering Add method
Leaving Add method
Leaving ngOnInit method
```

Comment: Sometimes the method has async content so the method end asynchronously. Is it possilbe to add a key inside the method which is commented but parsed for the decorator to know where to add the leave console line ?  //@LOGEND

Comment: @noririco I think this can be done. You have to replace the the original method with a async function and await the original method and then log the leave.

Comment: @zgue but the function itself is not async, it returns void, what do you think ?

Comment: It would be better if you ask this as separate question with a concrete code sample. So its hard to imagen what you want to do.