# How to debounce a method in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, debouncing

I have a method call `foo()` who is making an API call, and the `foo()` method is calling inside a slider `eventChange` method, the slider has a step of 100 while the `maxNum` is 500k+ so when someone slide the slider it will call the `eventChange` method more than 1 time.

Now I want to debounce the method `foo()` for 400ms before making the API call like we do on `FormControl` value changes.

I've tried something with lodash debounce

```
var debounce = _.debounce(function(){

  foo();

}, 30000);

debounce();
```

but it's saying that `foo()` is not a function. How can I debounce the method `foo()` with raw TypeScript.

**NOTE.** Foo() is not bind able to any html.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051273/angular-and-debounce ... specifically you should look at the answer that's most up-to-date for Angular 6/7+ : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52244384/419705

Comment: don't you think that, the answer only solving the debounce issue for FormControls and I've mentioned that already in my question , I want a TypeScript solution for a method to debounce.

Comment: @Frozen_Peas you didn't read my question well, the links you are giving I have gone through, that's why I'm asking on SO. thanks btw.

Comment: Unless you forgot to hit "save" on an edit, you did not (and still do not) mention reading through any questions. You mention using lodash for some reason rather than anything within Angular itself. "foo()" being bindable to html is not relevant to anything. You ask how to debounce a method in angular 2+, and the answer is "use rxjs". If your actual question is "why does using Lodash debounce not work in this case', that is 100% not what your question says. :)

Comment: If your question is actually "How do I use lodash to debounce this function call?" then you'll need to provide more context, namely how you're invoking that code you've posted, and where 'foo()' is defined relative to it.

Comment: @Frozen_Peas again you commenting without reading or understanding my question, I'm not very good at English, but the question is clear for people who understand a little English, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, somehow I manage to solve the issue through `setTimeout` and it's working perfect for me as a debouncer,

```
onSliderEventChanges(event:ChangeContext){ 

  if(this.timerid !== null){
    clearTimeout(this.timerid);
  }
  this.timerid  = setTimeout(() => 
  {
    this.foo(false);
    this.timerid = null;
  }, 400);

}
```

The first if will always clear the last running `timeOut`, so end of the sliding I will have only one call to the `foo()` as only the last `timeOut` is alive.

`setTimeout` always return a`timerId`.

Comment: I combined this answer with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47140375/3989826) to make my own debounce decorator

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lodash-decorators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-decorators) to apply lodash operations to functions with ease

```
@debounce(1000)
foo() { ... }
```

It's especially useful for angular components or services which are all class based.

Comment: thanks for the answer, now I have my own debouncer, I think I won't need any stuff for debouncing a method anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of rxjs, since you are working in angular you have that library already available, and so you have a debounce function ready to use on it.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // you look for your html element in which you desire
    // to attach an eventListener 
    let myHtmlElement = document.querySelector("#my-element-id-name");
    // then we proceed to turn the event into an observable sequence
    // my event could be in your case the 'click' event, I believe
    const myEventVar$ = fromEvent(myHtmlElement , 'myEvent');
    myEventVar$.pipe(
      // debounceTime is the rxjs library to delay the firing 
      // of function foo by 400ms in this example
      debounceTime(400)
    ).subscribe( () => {
      this.foo();
    });
}
```